# Dates increment by row

Tags: oracle

I have one table (in Oracle database) in which Date column is empty (NULL). table has 100 rows. I want to fill (insert or update) date column starting from aug-15-2017 and increment date by one day in every next row.

I explain it - in first row date should be Aug-15-2017, in second row date should be Aug-16-2017, in third row date should be Aug-17-2017 and so on ...
Kindly help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET dt =  TO_DATE('AUG-14-2017','MON-DD-YYY') + ROWNUM
WHERE dt is null
```

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)

Comment: The table is not guaranteed to be updated in order using this - `ROWNUM` will be assigned to rows in the order they are read and, if row movement has been enabled or rows are read in parallel,  you may find then dates are not in the expected order. You should instead, base the order off another column (assuming that you have one).

Comment: @MT0 a very valid comment but as you can see there were no requirements for ordering defined

Answer (score 0):

If you have another column (i.e. an `id` column) that you wish to ensure the order of the dates is based upon then you can use:

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dt = DATE '2017-08-14' + rn;
```

Using `ROWNUM` without an `ORDER BY` clause is not guaranteed to generate rows in the order you wish. You can see the difference in the following example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67410/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, dt1, dt2 ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL, CAST( NULL AS DATE ), CAST( NULL AS DATE )
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;

UPDATE table_name
SET dt1 = DATE '2017-08-14' + ROWNUM
WHERE dt1 IS NULL;

MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dt2 = DATE '2017-08-14' + rn;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67410/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                  DT1 |                  DT2 |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 | 2017-08-18T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-15T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2017-08-22T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-16T00:00:00Z |
|  3 | 2017-08-23T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-17T00:00:00Z |
|  4 | 2017-08-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-18T00:00:00Z |
|  5 | 2017-08-20T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-19T00:00:00Z |
|  6 | 2017-08-17T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-20T00:00:00Z |
|  7 | 2017-08-19T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-21T00:00:00Z |
|  8 | 2017-08-21T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-22T00:00:00Z |
|  9 | 2017-08-16T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-23T00:00:00Z |
| 10 | 2017-08-24T00:00:00Z | 2017-08-24T00:00:00Z |
```